# Array push not working in a function? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I'm Trying to get 5 dates (`$completion_date`) into an array I have a list I'm looping through passing the `$completion_date` to the function below there are multiple instances of the same `$completion_date` in the list but I only want one of each in the array  `$completion_dates = [];` so each time I search the array using `array_search($completion_date, $completion_dates);` and if the current `$completion_date` isn't there I want to add it to the array and if it is I want to modify `$completions` and `$payouts` at the same position in their respective arrays. My problem is array_push doesn't seem to push all the dates? only one?

And I've checked the if statement that array_push is in and it's running the else clause every time (as array_push isn't working to change that);

```
function sortResults($completion_date, $payout){
    global $completion_dates, $completions, $payouts;

    $completion_dates = [];
    $completions = [0,0,0,0,0]; // not in use
    $payouts = [0,0,0,0,0]; // not in use


    // check is $completion_date is in $completion_dates array and get position if so.
    $position = array_search($completion_date, $completion_dates);

    if ($position) {
        // update $payouts and $completions @ same $position.
    }else{
        // add $completion_date to $completion_dates array.
        array_push($completion_dates, $completion_date);
    }

}


var_dump($completion_dates);
```

outputs: `array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "22/01/2017" }`

But should output four other dates `"18/01/2017"`, `"19/01/2017"`, `"20/01/2017"`, `"21/01/2017`" as well?

the data i'm looping through is escaping the dates like so `{"completion_date":"18\/01\/2017","0":"18\/01\/2017","payout":"13.20","1":"13.20"}` not sure if it matters, it really shouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

Because you overwrite $completion_dates each time in your function.

```
function sortResults($completion_date, $payout)
{
    global $completion_dates, $completions, $payouts;

    $completion_dates = []; <----------------------- HERE
    $completions = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // not in use
    $payouts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // not in use


    // check is $completion_date is in $completion_dates array and get position if so.
    $position = array_search($completion_date, $completion_dates);

    if ($position) {
        // update $payouts and $completions @ same $position.
    } else {
        // add $completion_date to $completion_dates array.
        array_push($completion_dates, $completion_date);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats not gonna work either. It also sounds clearer to declare your globals  at start outside functions to keep trace of them.  global  $completion_dates=array();

Comment: even with the array outside, the global doesn't seem to work? even with the comment's help above.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/RFuxAKyU this doesn't work either?  (when called)